# Как определить чётность номера итерации цикла в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, html, django

Мне нужно чередовать в шаблоне класс контейнера **`div`**

---

```
{% for smth in smth_list %}
{% if (forloop.counter % 2 != 0) %}  <!-- Ошибка в этом месте -->
<div class="container container-1">
       {{ smth }}
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="container container-2">
       {{ smth }}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Этот код выдает ошибку:

> Could not parse the remainder:
> '(forloop.counter' from
> '(forloop.counter'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фильтр [divisibleby](http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/ref/templates/builtins.html#divisibleby)

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

Comment: @breaf, спасибо огромное...

Answer (score 7):

Вообще, такое принято делать немного по-другому, через [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

```
{% for smth in smth_list %}
    <div class="container {% cycle 'container-1' 'container-2' %}">
        {{ smth }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Каждый раз, когда будет встречаться тег `cycle`, будет чередоваться и подставляться значение из списка указанных.

Или, если нужно не выводить, а держать в переменной (скажем, использовать значение несколько раз), то так:

```
{% for smth in smth_list %}
    {% cycle 'container-1' 'container-2' as smth_container silent %}
    <div class="container {{ smth_container }}">
        {{ smth }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```